# How to create an offset for the text displayed in an input?

Tags: html, css, input

I am creating a basic log in function, really nothing fancy.
[image]

this is what I have right now, but this is what I would like to have:

[image]

I don't just want to add spaces, since, when the user clicks the input field it clears the input. But I don't just want to clear it to another space as the user would be able to delete that then. I want a premade property to have that little one space-offset on the left, preferably ignored if I evaluate the input later on.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show us the relevant code you're using now?

Comment: It's not better to use placeholder parameter to do this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you try padding :

```css
.username
{
  padding-left : 10px;
}
```

```html
<input type = 'text' class='username' value='Enter username'>
```

Answer (score 5):

Use
`input{ padding-left: 10px; }`

Answer (score 3):

Using css `padding-left` on your input  , see below snippet :

```css
.login-input {
  padding-left:10px;
}
```

```html
<input class="login-input" type="text" placeholder="enter username" /><br/><br/>
<input class="login-input" type="text" placeholder="enter password" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Use padding property to input.

```css
input{
padding-left:10px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="this is sample text"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that I understand what you want:

You need that help text `please enter your user name...` to be blank when the user click on the `input field` ?!

**TO DO SO :**

```
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="please enter your user name..."/>
```